# Select where mysqli php not returning result

Tags: php, select, mysqli, where-clause

Here's my code

```
<?php
// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $pwd, $db_name);
// check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected ";
$select_query = 'SELECT * FROM ftrpm WHERE (my_id = "" || my_id IS NULL)';
$selected = mysqli_query($conn, $select_query);
var_dump($selected);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I get no results.

```
Connected 
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) 
{ 
  ["current_field"]=> int(0) 
  ["field_count"]=> int(15) 
  ["lengths"]=> NULL 
  ["num_rows"]=> int(1) 
  ["type"]=> int(0) 
}
```

Same query works perfectly fine on my phpmyadmin. What is wrong?

Comment: fetch your  `$selected` first to get the results  (There is one record `["num_rows"]=> int(1)` in your `$selected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `var_dump()` you see that there are in fact rows returned, you can tell by `["num_rows"]=> int(1)`.

You just need to fetch it first, using `mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected);`.

```
$selected = mysqli_query($conn, $select_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected);
var_dump($row);
// Can be accessed with indexes the same as the colum-name, like 
// $row['id']
```

If you have multiple rows, you can loop over them with

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected)) {
    // Use $row here
}
```

- http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc

Comment: Thanks. That helps

Comment: @RubenKannan If this answer solved your issue, and you feel this was the best answer given, please accept it as solved. See [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :-)

Comment: I was testing the solution. It works and I marked this as answered. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query()` returns a object

if you want to fetch rows you have to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected){
    //here you can access your data one by one row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $pwd, $db_name);
    // check connection 
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected ";
    $select_query = 'SELECT * FROM ftrpm WHERE (my_id = "" || my_id IS NULL)';
    $selected = mysqli_query($conn, $select_query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected))
    {
        var_dump($row); 
    } 
    mysqli_close($conn);
```